# Xamarin.Forms Grid Layout

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm sort of a beginner in Xamarin.Forms App. And I'm struggling with `GridLayout`.
And this what I want to fix:

[image]

How to write this in grid layout and where am I going wrong? I have been working for an entire day, trying out new combinations of code. But nothing seems to help. Here is my code:

```
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });


grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });

grid.Children.Add(itemName, 1, 0);
grid.Children.Add(delete, 2, 2);


Grid.SetRowSpan(itemName, 3);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(delete, 3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding tells me you trying to add a number of items with a delete button next to each of them that are aligned at the right side every time so how I would design it is something like:

**XAML**

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
     <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" />
    <Image Grid.Column="1" />
  </Grid>
```

And then use a [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/) or [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/) to form multiple list items!

Goodluck feel free to get back if you have queries

Comment: Yes, But I.m trying to do it from the code-behind. And also, Do you mean I shall have a single row for this layout? Some large line items doesn't fit

Comment: I'm not using any ListView, just gridlayout. Any more help?

Comment: Happy to help, please get back to me in case if you have queries!

Answer (score 0):

`Grid` is good setting setting layout of fixed number of Row or Columns. 
If you are looking for Layouts growing with number of Items use [StackLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/stack-layout) [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview?view=xamarin-forms) or [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/) for your UI requirement.

Use Xaml instead of cs for layouting, it saves a lot of time and is a lot easier to read.

Comment: It has to be done using cs as the line items are fetched from a database

Comment: Use StackLayout or ListView if you are fetching data and don't know the Items count. Grid with dynamic row is possible but is not a better way.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is only one row definition and 2 column definitions. I recommend to use either [`ListView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/) or [`CollectionView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/) if you want to display a list of same objects.

If in case, if your list is small and would like to make it light weight, I recommend you to use Bindable Layout. [Refer my blog here for more details](https://xdevlogs.com/2020/01/04/bindable-layout-xamarin-forms/).

You can also use `StackLayout` and set its `Orientation` property to Horizontal for achieving the same result.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="YourText" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
    <Image Grid.Column="1" />
  </Grid>
```

Below is the code behind code.

```
var itemName = new Label() { Text="YourText", LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.WordWrap };
var delete = new Image() { Source="YourImageSource" };

grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });

grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });

grid.Children.Add(itemName, 0, 0);
grid.Children.Add(delete, 1, 0);
```

Note: You can use the `LineBreakMode` property of the Label to enable multiple line text. [Refer here for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.linebreakmode?view=xamarin-forms).